# Connect to Database via proxy a python script

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have a python script that connects to a remote MySQL database using the python library MySQLdb. It works fine but how can I get it to connect through a proxy that I'm behind when at work. I can connect via the command line in ssh, but how do I get the python script to use the proxy settings. There doesnt seem to be any options in the MySQLdb commands for proxy configurations.

```
   import MySQLdb as mdb

   conn=mdb.connect(host='mysite.com',user='myuser',passwd='mypassword',db='mydb')
   cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old post, but I thought I'd answer it anyway.
you can use your SSH connection as a proxy
The easiest way it to use `proxychains` 
The default port for proxychains is 9050 so when when you connect to the remote host include the `-D` parameter like:
`ssh -D 9050 -l user remotehost`
Then from a separate terminal window, or using `screen`, on your local machine any command you preface with `proxychains` is routed through the SSH server, for example:
`proxychains python myscript.py` will route all outbound TCP requests, whether a database connection or a urllib2/requests HTTP(S) request.
Proxychains is not specific to python, but anything.  You can just as easily launch a web browser or anything else.  Try `proxychains firefox` or `proxychains curl https://api.ipify.org`