# Make a MySQL Connection Over a Proxy

Tags: python, mysql, proxy

We have a Python script that writes values to a local database. We need to move this database to a remote host that requires the connection come from a white-listed IP address, which we have to set and forget.

Our solution is to use the proxy from another part of the Python sctipt (HTTP GET for something else). However, the MySQLDB library doesn't seem to allow for a proxy connection with authentication.

Our question... Are there any other librarys available, or perhaps another library or a MySQL solution to achieve this?

We found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383540/connect-to-database-via-proxy-a-python-script) but it's not much to go on, and doesn't seem to work. Note we can't use a system wide proxy.

TLDR: How can you connect to a MySQL Database via a proxy to solve a problem of needing to be connected through a static IP?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what type of solution do you need; permanent or temporary. 
But you can use `ssh` with `-L` switch.

```
ssh -L3307:localhost:3306 root@mysqlserver
```

now you can connect to port 3307 on your local computer. **You should define `host` and set it `127.0.0.1`**

Comment: We'll need a permanent solution, but an intermittent connection. i.e. Python would initiate the connection while it's running. Can you expand on your suggestion? I'm light on ssh. Are you saying that you open a temp connection with Python?

Comment: This is not pythonic way. You bind local 3307 port to mysql server's 3306 port and then connect to 127.0.0.1:3307 via every language or mysql-client

Comment: OK thanks I will look into this. Will it affect other connections on different ports for this client? I have other services that can't go through the proxy.